# Unexpected unicode symbols in Python JSON->Base64

Tags: python, json, unicode, base64

I got exe-binary on remote server. Its listening TCP port and wait from me JSON in Base64 format. I dont known language of this exe, i think it is C++. Nothing more about it.

I build valid JSON in python script and send it to TCP port:

```
payload = {...}
toSend = base64.b64encode(
            json.dumps(payload).encode('utf8')
        )

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(toSend)
```

Server exe write in log strange errors about non-existens unicode characters in my JSON.

```
payload = {'field': 'test'}
```

> sytax error while parsing object - invalid literal; last read: '"test"<U+0011>'; expected '}'

```
payload = {'field': 'test', 'some': 'blah'}
```

> sytax error while parsing object - invalid string: control character U+0000 (NUL) must be escaped to \u0000; last read '"bla<U+0000>'

Help please understand source of this trouble.

I try different values and fields sets, but every time server see some strange symbols in JSON.
I think this is Base64 decode problem. May be i using some characters which incomplitable with this server.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that the error seems to imply that a unicode character coding other than UTF-8 is expected.  Did you try encoding the JSON string using other encodings (UTF_16, UTF_32) or without .encode() ?  Given that one of the errors complains about an expected `}` character and escaping, it seems to be more likely that the error in in JSON parsing rather than base64 decoding.